# Package does not exist for Spring Boot project with Kotlin classes and Lombok

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, kotlin, lombok

I'm not sure if Lombok has anything to do with this, since I'm not using their annotations in any Kotlin files.

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.cas.eo.contentacq</groupId>
    <artifactId>content-acq-copper-manifest-writer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>content-acq-copper-manifest-writer</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.5.30-M1</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cas.eo.contentacq.dbresources</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbresources-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0-rc1</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`mvn package` output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------< org.cas.eo.contentacq:content-acq-copper-manifest-writer >------
[INFO] Building content-acq-copper-manifest-writer 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ content-acq-copper-manifest-writer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ content-acq-copper-manifest-writer ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to C:\Users\mxf63\gitrepo\content-acq-copper-manifest-writer\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[5,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[6,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[7,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.props does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[8,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.props does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[10,68] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.service does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[11,68] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.service does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/utils/Logging.java:[4,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[25,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ProcessProps
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.Controller
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[26,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AltRunProps
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.Controller
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[27,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JSONWriter
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.Controller
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[5,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[6,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[7,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[8,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[9,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.props does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[10,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.props does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[30,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TANProcessor
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.Controller
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[69,58] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EndInfo
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.Controller
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[21,1] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ProcessProps
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.Controller
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[28,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ProcessProps
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[29,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ManifestProps
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[31,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StartInfo
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[70,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StartInfo
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[111,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StartInfo
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[132,49] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StartInfo
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[152,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EndInfo
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[166,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EndInfo
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[180,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EndInfo
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[25,1] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ProcessProps
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/utils/Logging.java:[24,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EndInfo
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.utils.Logging
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Application.java:[4,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.props does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Application.java:[5,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.props does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/utils/ManifestSerializer.java:[7,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/utils/ManifestSerializer.java:[11,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Manifest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/utils/ManifestSerializer.java:[16,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Manifest
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.utils.ManifestSerializer
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/utils/ManifestSerializer.java:[21,27] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Manifest
  location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.utils.ManifestSerializer
[INFO] 36 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.606 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-30T08:56:35-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project content-acq-copper-manifest-writer: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[5,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[6,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[7,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.props does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[8,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.props does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[10,68] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.service does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[11,68] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.service does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/utils/Logging.java:[4,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[25,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ProcessProps
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.Controller
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[26,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class AltRunProps
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.Controller
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[27,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class JSONWriter
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.Controller
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[5,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[6,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[7,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[8,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[9,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.props does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[10,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.props does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[30,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TANProcessor
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.Controller
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[69,58] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class EndInfo
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.Controller
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Controller.java:[21,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ProcessProps
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.Controller
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[28,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ProcessProps
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[29,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ManifestProps
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[31,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class StartInfo
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[70,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class StartInfo
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[111,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class StartInfo
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[132,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class StartInfo
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[152,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class EndInfo
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[166,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class EndInfo
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[180,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class EndInfo
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/repo/CopperRepository.java:[25,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ProcessProps
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.repo.CopperRepository
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/utils/Logging.java:[24,40] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class EndInfo
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.utils.Logging
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Application.java:[4,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.props does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/Application.java:[5,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.props does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/utils/ManifestSerializer.java:[7,66] package org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/utils/ManifestSerializer.java:[11,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class Manifest
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/utils/ManifestSerializer.java:[16,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Manifest
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.utils.ManifestSerializer
[ERROR] /C:/Users/mxf63/gitrepo/content-acq-copper-manifest-writer/src/main/java/org/cas/eo/contentacq/contentacqcoppermanifestwriter/utils/ManifestSerializer.java:[21,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Manifest
[ERROR]   location: class org.cas.eo.contentacq.contentacqcoppermanifestwriter.utils.ManifestSerializer
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Each "symbol" that can't be found is a Kotlin file, and the locations where they can't be found are regular Java files. In cases where Kotlin files reference other Kotlin files, no error is apparent. Note that the code runs fine from within IntelliJ. I notice that the symbol in IntelliJ differs between some Kotlin files, and some are suffixed with ".kt" while others aren't:

[image: IntelliJ project structure]

Answer (score 0):

Since i also encountered this Problem. For me the following article was useful and solved my problem

[Using Kotlin class in Java: Cannot find symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980110/using-kotlin-class-in-java-cannot-find-symbol)